# Spring Aop Error of formal unbound pointcut

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-aop

Hi i am using spring Aop in my application i am getting an error for following lines of code
LoggingAspect.java

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Before("allCircleMethods()")
    public void loggingAdvice(Joinpoint joinPoint)
    {
        System.out.println("get method is called"+joinPoint.toString() );
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
    public void allGetters(){}


    @Pointcut("within(org.com.revanth.model.Circle)")
    public void allCircleMethods(){}
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Traingle.java

```
public class Traingle {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

ShapeService.java

```
public class ShapeService {

    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }
    public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }
    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }
    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

   <bean name="triangle" class="org.com.revanth.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Traingle Name"></property>
   </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="org.com.revanth.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle Name"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean name="shapeService" class="org.com.revanth.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName"/>   
   <bean name="loggingAspect" class="org.com.revanth.aspect.LoggingAspect"></bean>
</beans>
```

AopMain.java

```
public class AopMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ShapeService shapeService = (ShapeService) ctx.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
        System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
    }

}
```

I am getting an error of formal unbound in pointcut expression.the error stack trace is as follows:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.com.revanth.AopMain.main(AopMain.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me please to solve the above error?Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Pointcut("within(org.com.revanth.model.Circle)")
public void allCircleMethods(){}
```

should be

```
@Pointcut("within(org.com.revanth.model.Circle.*)")
public void allCircleMethods(){}
```

Comment: still i am getting the same error i don't know why?

Comment: are you sure about exact package and class that pointcut to be applied for?